# Error: pattern must be a RegExp using Joi framework nodejs

Tags: node.js, joi

I need to accept a mobile number as an input for example +97255555555. I need the user to enter first + sign and then only digits.

```js
  const LoginValidation = (data) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        phone: Joi.string().required().regex("/^([+]\d*)?$/"),
        passwordUser: Joi.string().required(),
    });
    return schema.validate(data);
  };
module.exports.LoginValidation = LoginValidation;
```

But I'm facing following issue while validating with Joi framework:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: regex must be a RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

```
let re = RegExp("/^([+]\d*)?$/";
const LoginValidation = (data) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        phone: Joi.string().required().regex(re),
        passwordUser: Joi.string().required(),
    });
    return schema.validate(data);
  };
```

It's just saying that rather than expecting a regex string. It's expecting a regex object.

(referece)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing to pattern instead of regex

```js
  const LoginValidation = (data) => {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        phone: Joi.string().required().pattern(/^([+]\d*)?$/),
        passwordUser: Joi.string().required(),
    });
    return schema.validate(data);
  };
module.exports.LoginValidation = LoginValidation;
```